# Jquery remove all select options - not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, sails.js

I've read solutions to this but for some reason I can't get it working.
To put this into context, I have 2 dropdowns, when an option is selected in one, I want to remove the options in the 2nd dropdown and reload them with data relevant to the first dropdown.

I'm actually using Sails, so will include the raw code below, however I have also created a JSFiddle with static content where I cant get it working either, this can be found here:
https://jsfiddle.net/wh5utw5j/1/

**Dropdown Page**

```
<div class="form-group" id="chainDrop">
  <label for="restaurantChain">What chain does it belong to?</label>
  <select class="form-control selectpicker" id="restaurantChain" name="restaurantChain" data-live-search="true" onchange="loadRestaurants()">
    <% if(typeof chains != "undefined") { %>
      <% _.each(chains, function(chain){ %>
        <option value="<%= chain.id %>">
          <%= chain.name %>
        </option>
        <% }) %>
          <% } %>
  </select>



  <p >The below will override the chain selection, and add items unique to the below restaurant in the chain</p>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-specific"> Add menu items to individual restaurants
    </label>
  </div>


  <div class="form-group" id="specific">
    <label for="individualRestaurant">Restaurant Name(Chain Override)</label>
    <select class="form-control selectpicker" id="individualRestaurant" name="individualRestaurant" data-live-search="true">
      <% if(restaurants) { %>
        <% _.each(restaurants, function(restaurant){ %>
          <% if(restaurant.chain) { %>
            <option value="<%= restaurant.id %>">
              <%= restaurant.name %>, <%= restaurant.location %>
            </option>
            <% } %>
          <% }) %>
      <% } %>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Function**

```
function loadRestaurants() {
  var editSpecific = $('#checkboxes-specific').is(':checked');

  if(editSpecific){
    $('#individualRestaurant').find('option').remove().end();
  }
}
```

I've tested that the function is executing and it is, but I'm stumped as to why the JQuery isn't working

**Update**

Im not sure if this is impacting it, however I am also using a Jquery function to toggle the visibility of divs

```
$(function() {
  $('[name="checkboxes"]').on('change', function() {
    $('#independantDrop').toggle($('#checkboxes-isindependant').is(':checked'));
    $('#chainDrop').toggle($('#checkboxes-ischain').is(':checked'));
    $('#specific').toggle($('#checkboxes-specific').is(':checked'));
  }).trigger('change');
});
```

As you can see, my checkbox in the code above hides/unhides the `specific` div.  I also have a checkbox before all my code above that hides/unhides the lot

I have also added the following code to my function to test the selector:

```
  var select = $('#individualRestaurant');
  console.log(select);
```

The results are:

```
[select#individualRestaurant.form-control.selectpicker, context: document, selector: "#individualRestaurant"]
```

**Update #2**

It looks like the root cause of this is a I am using it and it is modifying my dropdowns:
https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

The following code now works:

```
$('#restaurantChain').on('hidden.bs.select', function (e) {
  console.log('test');
  $('#individualRestaurant').find('[id=restaurantId]').remove();
  $('#individualRestaurant').selectpicker('refresh');
});
```

Comment: Are you wanting to remove a specific option, or all of the options from the second drop-down?

Answer (score 2):

Here above code working properly. Please check any error in your browser console and below code

[image]

Javascript

```
function loadRestaurants() {
    var editSpecific = $('#checkboxes-specific').is(':checked');
    console.log(editSpecific);
    if (editSpecific) {
        $('#dbSearch').find('option').remove().end();
    }
}
```

Html

```
 <div class="col-sm-3">
                <select id="dbReader" onchange="loadRestaurants()"class="form-control"><option
                        value="-1">All Readers</option>
                    <c:forEach items="${readers}" var="reader">
                        <option value="${reader.id}">${reader.name}</option>
                    </c:forEach></select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <select id="dbSearch" class="form-control">
                    <option value="TODAY">Today</option>
                    <option value="YESTERDAY">Yesterday</option>
                    <option value="WTD">WTD</option>
                    <option value="MTD">MTD</option>
                    <option value="CUSTOM">CUSTOM</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

Comment: There are no errors in the console.  I can, and have put other jquery in the function to post data which works

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set completely empty the drop-down, you could set the HTML to be 'blank'.

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/wh5utw5j/4/

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group" id="chainDrop">
  <label for="restaurantChain">What chain does it belong to?</label>
  <select class="form-control selectpicker" id="restaurantChain" name="restaurantChain" data-live-search="true">
            <option value="1">One</option>
            <option value="2">Two</option>
            <option value="3">Three</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group" id="specific">
    <label for="individualRestaurant">Restaurant Name(Chain Override)</label>
    <select class="form-control selectpicker" id="individualRestaurant" name="individualRestaurant" data-live-search="true">
            <option value="1">One</option>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#restaurantChain').change(function() {
        $('#individualRestaurant').html(''); // Empty the options
        // Do something else here
    });
});
```

I've also updated it to bind the change to the first drop-down, instead of having it in-line.

Comment: I've just tested this and I have the same problem

Comment: Is the function firing at all - are you debugging it?

It could be that the element doesn't exist as your page may not be fully loaded. Is you code in the $(document).ready() function?

I've updated my example above.

Comment: Yep, the function is firing. Popping a simple console.log('test') inside the function shows the result in the console when the select option is changed

Answer (score 1):

As Bootstrap-select.js is in use, the following code should be used:

```
$('#restaurantChain').on('hidden.bs.select', function (e) {
  $('#individualRestaurant').find('[id=restaurantId]').remove();
  $('#individualRestaurant').selectpicker('refresh');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

good job for including the jsfiddle. I suspect the problem is not putting the loadrestaurants function in the root scope. In your fiddle it's in the "on load" function.

[image: jsfiddle settings]

Comment: Thanks.  That fixes the jsfiddle but not my own code.  I know JQuery is loading as I can post data from this function just fine.

Comment: I've just added some more code, wondering if this is causing a clash

Comment: Could you maybe update the jsfiddle and share the link in a comment here so that I can see whats not working now

Comment: Martin - I actually found that bootstrap-select was causing the problem.  I've updated my original post with the answer

Comment: Hey, good job and good luck developing your sais application.